# swift: iOS show alert action depending to a condition

Tags: ios, swift, alert

I have my code below which trigger an alert but I want to trigger alert and show only actions depending on the condition for example in the condition below if result is true then I only want to show alert 1 else show alert 2

show alert action depending to condition

```
var a = loggedInUsername

if ((a?.range(of: "mother")) != nil) {
    print("true")
    print ("name:" , loggedInUsername)
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("ACTION 1 selected!")
    })

    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Approve Chore", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    })
```

Comment: `if-else`; `if-else if`; `guard-else`; pick a flow control

Comment: create the common alertcontroller, and pass the title && message based on your condition

Comment: that is just a single alert

Comment: condition for your UIAlertAction or UIAlertController

Comment: Add your alert action using if-else condition. 
if action1 {
  alert.addAction(action1)
}

Comment: for those who want to answer just post so i can vote and mark it as useful thanks

Comment: Thank @Anbu.karthik

Comment: thanks to all who answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show `UIAlertAction` conditionally.Like if your condition is true than you want to show `action1` and if condition is false than you want to show `action2`.

Try this.

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: AppName, message: "YOUR MESSAGE", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.tintColor = Colors.NavTitleColor
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    })
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Approve Chore", style: .cancel, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

    })

    if ((a?.range(of: "mother")) != nil) {
        alert.addAction(action1)
    }
    else {
        alert.addAction(action2)
    }

    present(alert, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
```

**If you want to add Image before `UIAlertAction` title than use below code.**

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "YOUR MESSAGE", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.view.tintColor = Colors.NavTitleColor

    let image1 = UIImage(named: "attendance")
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: nil)
    action1.setValue(image1, forKey: "image")

    let image2 = UIImage(named: "mail")
    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Approve Chore", style: .default, handler: nil)
    action2.setValue(image2, forKey: "image")

    alert.addAction(action1)
    alert.addAction(action2)

    present(alert, animated: true) {() -> Void in }
```

**Looks like below image.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

lets say this is your alert controller

```
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Alert", message: "This is an alert.", preferredStyle: .alert)
```

boolean var for showing action

```
var shouldShowAction1 = true //change it programmatically based on your requirement
```

your actions

```
    let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("ACTION 1 selected!")
    })

    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Approve Chore", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    })
```

add actions to alert based on condition

```
if shouldShowAction1{
   alert.addAction(action1)
}else{
   alert.addAction(action2)
}
```

display alert

```
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thanks , for the answer

Comment: Hey @DurnKurvirck mark it as approved if you got the answer. Thanks

Comment: Ive appreciated all the answers guys but i can only mark one

Answer (score 0):

You can Possibly Use like this:

```
var isShowWhichAction:Int = 0

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "My Alert", message: "Your Message Here", preferredStyle: .alert)

let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        print("ACTION 1 selected!")
    })

    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Approve Chore", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
    })

if isShowWhichAction == 1{ // change the condition it according to your requirement
 alert.addAction(action2) //Condition True
}else{
 alert.addAction(action1) //Condition False
}
```

**Use it like this:**

```
    var a = loggedInUsername
    if ((a?.range(of: "mother")) != nil) {
        print ("name:" , loggedInUsername)
        isShowWhichAction = 1
    }else{
       isShowWhichAction = 0
    }
```

Hope this Help

### Edit

**To add image into it:**

```
var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40))
imageView.image = yourImage
alert.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

Comment: all the sincere answers acutally help. Thank You Guys , i hope i can mark all as correct

Comment: also i wanted to ask can we put image or label to an action ? aside from title? or can we replace title with image?

Comment: You can go for an custom alert or popup. that would make your task easy @DurnKurvirck

Comment: ah i see , but on putting on imag? how can we add image to alert action?

Comment: var imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(220, 10, 40, 40))
imageView.image = yourImage

alert.view.addSubview(imageView) @DurnKurvirck Edited the answer

Comment: ill try that idea Sir

Comment: @DurnKurvirck, if you want to add image before `UIAlertAction` title, review my updated answer.